# Formatted references: How to put "Year of publication" in round parentheses rather than square brackets

Tags: natbib, parentheses

Currently my reference appear in the

> **References**
>
> 1. Aggarwal, C. C. [2015], Data Mining: The Textbook, Springer Publishing
>      Company, Incorporated.
> 2. Han, J. [2005], Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques, Morgan Kaufmann
>      Publishers Inc., San Francisco, CA, USA.

Whereas, I need to put year in round parentheses, as in

> **References**
>
> 1. Aggarwal, C. C. (2015), Data Mining: The Textbook, Springer Publishing
>      Company, Incorporated.
> 2. Han, J. (2005), Data Mining: Concepts and Techniques, Morgan Kaufmann
>      Publishers Inc., San Francisco, CA, USA.

---

I have made the following changes in my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[sort,numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The code snippet you show suggests you are using `natbib` and not `biblatex`, yet you have tagged your question with `biblatex`. Can you clarify which bibliography package and style you use in an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)?

Comment: Thanks for quick replies

I am using natbib and  \bibliographystyle{agsm}

Answer (score 1):

(revised answer after receiving information from OP that `agsm` bibliography style is in use)

Since you're using the `agsm` bibliography style along with the `natbib` citation management package, you need to add the following two instructions in the preamble (after loading the `natbib` package):

```
\renewcommand\harvardyearleft{(}
\renewcommand\harvardyearright{)}
```

That way, you'll still get the citation call-outs in numeric style, surrounded by square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

It doesn't work. I checked it already. This changes the entire referencing in my document body into parentheses (). I need  parentheses ONLY in References .

Comment: @Faaiz - Please see the updated answer, which I posted after you provided a vital piece of information, *viz.*, that you use the `agsm` bibliography style.

Comment: @ dear Mico - Many many thanks :)  

Issue resolved and now the format is as per the requirements given to me.

First i tried to search the solution for around one hour but could not get success, that is why, i posted my question. You solved in minutes !!

Thanks